# About Differentiability of a function at a certain point

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have encounter a problem on differentiability on a function. Some help will be appreciated!

Problem is as follows:

$Q:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is a function defined by
$$Q(a,b) = \begin{cases}0&(a,b) = 0\\
\dfrac{\ln(-a^4-b^4+1)}{4a^2+4b^2}&(a,b) \ne 0\end{cases}$$

Show that $Q$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$. If not, state the reason.

My attempt:

For the $(0,0)$ part, I tried to find $Q(a, 0) = \frac{\ln(-a^4+1)}{4a^2}$.

Then I tried to find the partial derivatives of $Q(0, 0)$ w.r.t $a$ at $(a,b) = (0,0)$.

$$Q_a(0,0) = \frac d{da}\left(\dfrac{\ln(-a^4+1)}{4a^2}\right) = \dfrac{-a}{1-a^4}-\dfrac{\ln(1-a^4)}{2a^3}$$ which is undefined at $a = 0$.

And I have no clue how to go on from this.

For the $(0, 1)$ part, I am not sure whether I need to just differentiate $\frac{\ln(-a^4-b^4+1)}{4a^2+4b^2}$

at $(0, 1)$ or other methods to start the process.

Comment: You have only shown that away from $a = 0, Q_a(a,0)$ is equal to a function that is undefined at $a = 0$. You have not shown that $Q_a(a,0)$ must continue to behave like that function at $a = 0$. I.e., you have not shown that $Q_a(0,0)$ is itself undefined. In particular, I suggest you examine the behavior of $Q_a$ close to $0$. For the second part, note that $Q$ is undefined at $(0,1)$.

Comment: I see, thank you!